# regex for search json in log

Tags: regex, python-2.7, rfc

I have to capture the data in the SD located in logs (RFC5424). I created a regex for this. Unfortunately, there are data in json format and set '[' and ']'. Can someone help me make a regex that correctly captures this data?
Example:

```
import re
text = """[exampleSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][examplePriority@32473 class="{"fruits": [{ "kiwis": 3,"mangos": 4,"apple": null},{ "bag": true }],"vegetables": {"patatoes": "amandine","peas": false},"meat": ["fish","chicken","beef"]}"]"""
regex = """\[(\S+@[^\]]+)\]""" 
matchAllSD = re.findall(regex, text)
for SD in matchAllSD:
    print SD
```

$python `main.py`

```
exampleSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"

examplePriority@32473 class="{"fruits": [{ "kiwis": 3,"mangos":
4,"apple": null},{ "bag": true }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```
\[([^\]]*?(?:class=".*")?)\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WvU6Mp/2)